# The webpage loads extremely slow on https connection but works perfectly on http

Tags: google-chrome, http, web-applications, https, webserver

I am using goahead Webserver for my web application. The webpage loads extremely slow on https connection but works perfectly on http. Issue is worse while using chrome only.

[image]